# How to avoid browser opening while running selenium without using phantomjs & htmlunitdriver

Tags: java, jsoup

i extract some data from webpage,i have use phantomjs but it shows phantomjs console++ error . so please tell me another way to minimize the browser

Answer (score 0):

You can't minimize phantomjs, since it is a headless browser. You can use https://github.com/MachinePublishers/jBrowserDriver jbrowser driver instead of phantomjs.